# How to resolve comments outside the editor in ckeditor 5 for angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

How to resolve comments outside the editor in ckeditor 5 for angular, while resolving the comments the comment annotation is not removing.

In my scenario when i add the comment and then resolve the comment without going back in the web page resolve comment is working fine, but if i go back and and then come again the annotation comment button  was not removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
constructor(private readonly commentsRepository: CommentsRepository) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.commentsRepository.on('resolveCommentThread', (event) => {
  const annotation = event.annotation;
  annotation.remove();
});
}
```

Comment: There are multiple comments in single page,  need to pass focusable  element in order to remove it.
 
In my scenario when i add the comment and then resolve the comment without going  back in the web page resolve comments working fine, but if i go back and and then come again the annotation comment button is not get removed